# HttpContext.Response unreliable in Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Ever since I upgraded to VSC 2017 I've noticed that HttpContext.Response functions have become very tricky to work with, as the expected error, "The thread was being aborted" is rarely handled correctly. Sometimes it works, but it's just as likely that it will hit that error and just quit.

I've tried the usual steps for handling this error myself: adding

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

at the end of Response.Redirect commands for example, but these have no effect.

Specific example: I have an application that exports GridViews to Excel spreadsheets. Following the the steps to gather and format my data for the spreadsheet, the file is created with the below steps.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
  var resp = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
  resp.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  resp.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + FileName + ".xlsx");
  excel.SaveAs(memoryStream);
  memoryStream.WriteTo(resp.OutputStream);
  resp.Flush();
  resp.End();
}
```

You can see that Response is being explicitly ended, but it still fails with the same error. It doesn't matter what browser I'm on, and I'm using .NET Framework 4.5.2 -- it's the highest the server I deploy to supports. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In further investigation, I have determined that Response, in all its various applications, doesn't play well with the AJAX Update Panel control. When I moved the LinkButton that fires the gridview-to-spreadsheet function I described above out my update panel, it ran as expected.

So don't trigger Response.[whatever] inside an update panel.

Answer (score 2):

In Vs 2017 using Core that  not support `HttpContext.Current`
so basically instead of that they provide some other thing

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

you can access like this in VS 2017

Hope so the answer is helpful to you

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help. I'm using "standard" .NET, not Core, so I can't make use of this interface. Thanks for the suggestion, though.